# HTML5 embedded video memory leak regardless of source or browser

Tags: html, youtube, html5-video

I have been building a streaming chatroom page and started to notice during my stress tests that it would grind to a halt after about 30m - 1h, after isolating all my ajax scripts I finally narrowed it down to the actual video itself, and it seems to happen in both IE and Chrome, both youtube and ustream. Even just browsing to the embedded video URL thus removing my code from the equation completely shows the problems persistence. The problem even compounds when in video ads from ustream pop up as it eats a chunk of memory and does not seam to garbage collect. Any ideas, comments, suggestions?

I am on a fresh Win10 install with nothing but note plus plus and all the latest windows updates, and no not insider builds.

[image: Memory usage graph]